# File name format <filename_yyyymmdd> in bash

Tags: bash, shell

A new file is created for each date and the contents are copied till the dashed line with the below code : I wanted the file name to be in the format 'filename_YYYYMMDD' using sub. Date of the file is taken from the input file

```
awk -F' ' '{
    fn=$1".log";
    sub(/^.* /,"",fn);
    print>fn;
    close(fn)
            }' \
    FS='\n' OFS='\n' RS='---+\n' ORS='' $1
```

Input file:

```
Date: 10-01-2007
There is abundance of plants in this region.
----------------------------------------------
Date: 10-01-2010
There are no trees now in this region
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Could anyone please help on the above question?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to save the date in a variable.

```
date=$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

If `fn` were your filename variable, the value for fn would be `fn=$filename"_"$date".log"`